# Running background tasks in Flask using Django

Tags: python, django, flask, celery, background-process

I have a web application built fully using Flask, at the moment the entire project runs on flask, i'm using many flask libraries for various functionality. However, some of these tasks i am running are very time consuming and take around 5 minutes to finish, and because of this if someone was to run this task and someone else wanted to navigate the website they would be stuck loading while the other lengthy task is done.

I'm currently looking for ways to finish running this task in the background so that users can freely navigate the website without being held hostage for 5 minutes while processing is done, I looked into Celery but would rather not use it. Someone instead suggested that I integrate Django to handle this instead, is this feasible, if so how?

Here is a quick sample of the current code I have:

```
@app.route("/apple/newoffercodes/<int:appID>", methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def newoffercodes(appID):
    application = ApplicationApple.query.filter_by(appleID=appID).first_or_404()
    package_name = application.appleID
        form = offerCode()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            filename = form.file.data
            result = createSubscriptionOffer(filename)
            if result == 200 or result == 201:
                flash("Offer Code Created Successfully","success")
                return redirect(url_for('offercodes',appID=appID))
            else:
                flash("An error has occurred while creating the offer. Please check Apple Connect.", "danger")
                return redirect(url_for('offercodes',appID=appID))
        return render_template('newOfferCodeApple.html', form=form, application=application)
```

In the example above, `result = createSubscriptionOffer(filename)` takes around 5 minutes to finish processing, and this is one of the functions I would like to use Django to run in the background.

If someone could shed some light on this I would greatly appreciate it! Any suggestions on the possible implementations would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**About running background tasks:** if you want to run background tasks and don't want to integrate Celery into your project (understandable, because Celery is complex) - you can look into [something like RQ](https://python-rq.org/), but you need to set Redis backend for it (install it on your host machine, or set up Docker container with Redis, for example).

**About Django:** Django is not a tool for running background tasks - it is a framework built for the similar purposes as Flask, but much more complex. If you're using Flask for your project and already have different library dependencies associated with Flask - it seems counter-productive to switch to Django at this moment.

For example - when you're using Flask you should install additional libraries to achieve desired functionality (as you did, because Flask is very barebone by nature), but in Django you have many settings and modules enabled by default, it has his own ORM, integrated template engine, etc.

In short - Django is completely different story, much more opinionated and huge than Flask, so you definitely need to invest some time if you wish to migrate your project from Flask to Django.

Comment: I wasn't really looking to make the switch to Django, rather I was looking to implement both Flask and Django side by side, so for example the entire application would still run on Flask, but I would leverage Django's ability to run background tasks. That is what someone suggested to me, i'm not entirely sure if that's a viable option or not though

Comment: If you do as someone suggested - then you will have two web-applications instead of one ;) In this case no, it is not a viable option. If you want to keep using Flask - check flask-rq library and [this article about task query implementation](https://realpython.com/flask-by-example-implementing-a-redis-task-queue/)

Comment: Alright thanks, appreciate the help! Will definitely give flask-rq a try in that case!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way is to integrate redis-celery. The learning curve with celery-redis could be steep in the first steps, but after all, it will be useful to other cases and apps. Also, splitting the application into separate services could be a good practice. A webhook could be used to interact between app and long-time services. Finally, your createSubscriptionOffer function takes a lot of time (5 minutes is a full life), You should search for bottlenecks in the function.

Comment: The reason for the long processing time behind this function is that it is completely reliant on getting API responses from APIs offered by Apple's app store connect, which always take a while to send back the data, and there are many API requests being sent from my side, which is why it takes a while

Comment: have you tried with webhooks? I think that webhooks are a better approach instead of using a messages queue for background tasks.